# Rescaling x-axis data in Paraview

Tags: visualization, paraview

I am working with VTK legacy files containing vector information. The files have incremental extension representing a file series as defined by [this](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Animating_legacy_VTK_file_series) link.

When applying the filter "Plot Selection over Time", I get a nice curve as follows: [image]

However the x-axis does not show the realtime, rather it shows the actual time step. I would like to preserve the same data but have it show the x axis from 0 to 1 seconds rather than from 0 to 100 time steps.

I've searched up and down for a further filter that I can apply to the plot that can do this but haven't found one. Also the "Bottom axis custom scale" property does not help since it truncates the data after 1 second rather than rescaling it. I feel like there should be a relatively straightforward way to accomplish this on Paraview. Any ideas?

Comment: Export the plot to a csv file. It seems like it'd be easiest to take care of the plotting in Matlab/Python/<insert favorite plotting tool>.

Answer (score 1):

As @TylerOlsen suggests, it is probably a good idea to do this particular plot using another tool. But if you insist on doing it using Paraview, you can

1. Apply a Temporal Shift Scale Filter; and
2. Then plot over the shifted/scaled time.

In my example below I scaled my time by 0.1, turning the maximum to 25 (it has 250 timesteps).

[image]